# Padding of Floating Action Buttons in CustomView

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I've got 3 Action Buttons. One Scanbutton and (if some conditions are triggered) two more "minifab's". The Scanbutton should be in the `bottom|end` position and the other two should appear on top of it. 
I use the auto-generated CustomView Android Studio gave me. Now I want to know how I can change the position of my fab's. I cant use the padding-option. Is this because of the CustomView?

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SlideMenu">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/exportbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will work for you I have changed the CoOrdinate Layout to RelativeLayout and each button will sit one over the other , You still can set it by giving padding for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SlideMenu">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/exportbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/savebutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scanbutton" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Can you explain whats the problem with the CustomView? Or do I need a specific Layout to move my buttons?

Comment: Well When we user RelativeLayout helps us to move around the buttons, but it is not entirely recommended because when the screensize changes the relativity also will change and cause the buttons to go else where...
In your case this will not happen as the button1 is at bottom and other buttons are relative to it ...

Comment: I discovered a new problem. The whole Fragment seems to move behind the Action Bar. I think this depends to the changed View. Any ideas?

http://imgur.com/H6RIziU

Answer (score 0):

Solved it ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SlideMenu">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/exportbutton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:layout_above="@+id/savebutton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/savebutton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/savebutton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
            android:layout_above="@+id/scanbutton"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scanbutton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```